# Qt Call fails in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, boost

I've developed an application using Qt, VS2013 and Boost. It runs fine in Debug mode. But fails to run in Release mode. Here's a piece of code that runs fine while debugging but throws an exception in release mode:

```
std::string str = ui.labels->toPlainText().toStdString();
```

This call on the other hand works fine:

```
QString str = ui.labels->toPlainText();
```

Is there anything wrong with those lines of code? Other boost calls work fine. 
Thanks.

Comment: *What* exception does it generate?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to do too many things at once, and that makes it hard to pinpoint where it fails. Try it step-by-step:

```
QString const text = ui.labels->toPlainText();
QByteArray const utf8 = text.toUtf8();
auto const str = utf8.toStdString();
```